# How to switch between two field value under some condition?

Tags: sql, linq, select, informix

With a table like this:

```
id  doc_before  doc_after
0      100
1      167         153
2      132
```

---

I want  to get the `doc_after` if exist else get the `doc_before`.

How to do this ?

I want the result like this :

```
0    100
1    153
2    132
```

Comment: do you want this in sql or vb/c#?

Comment: also, what have you tried?

Comment: i want `sql` but if there's no way i want some way in `linq`

Comment: Please remember that tables have names; include a table name in your question!  Also, since you say that you need to track the source of the data (which column the value came from), the question should be updated to include that requirement.  Also, as a general rule with any DBMS-related question, it is a good idea to indicate which version of the DBMS you are using or interested in.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :Thanks a lot for your advices ,i'll take care of that in the next questions :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement. This is the supported Informix syntax.

```
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN nvl(doc_after,'') <> '' THEN doc_after ELSE doc_before END AS doc
, CASE WHEN nvl(doc_after) <> '' THEN 'doc_after' ELSE 'doc_before' END AS camefrom
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: You might want to add `IS NOT NULL` to the condition to cater for NULL values.

Comment: but is there some way to know if it comes from `doc_after` or `doc_before`

Comment: you could add another item to your `SELECT` statement. I updated my answer

Comment: Actually, with informix you have to use nvl(), not isnull().  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1002.htm

Comment: there's a one syntax error :

`SELECT ID, CASE WHEN nvl(doc_after,'') <> '' THEN doc_after ELSE doc_before END AS doc
, CASE WHEN nvl(doc_after,'') <> '' THEN 'doc_after' ELSE 'doc_before' END AS docitcamefrom
FROM yourtable`

the second `nvl`

Comment: If you're going to use NVL, surely it should be `NVL(doc_after, doc_before)` in place of the whole of the first CASE.  I'm not convinced about the NVL for the second CASE, but it is more nearly legitimate.  If the `doc_*` columns are numeric, I'd argue NVL is unnecessary; if the `doc_*` columns are strings, then maybe NVL should be used, though blank but non-null strings are a trifle unusual.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id
  , COALESCE(doc_after, doc_before) AS the_doc
FROM the_table
   ;
```

Comment: It is an ANSI function, could have an other name in sybase. (in oracle it is called IFNULL(), IIRC)

Comment: `SELECT task_code
  , nvl(pdf_column , db_name) AS the_doc
FROM df1task
   ;`
this works with me but can't determine which field the data comes from

Comment: Why do you care what fields the data comes from?  It wasn't part of your original question and I don't see it as useful information.

Comment: @DanBracuk : it's important for me :)

Answer (score 1):

A more idiomatic use of the CASE would avoid using NVL:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN doc_after IS NULL THEN doc_before ELSE doc_after END AS doc_number,
       CASE WHEN doc_after IS NULL THEN 'B'        ELSE 'A'       END AS doc_source
  FROM AnonymousTable;
```

Clearly the coding 'A' for 'after' and 'B' for 'before' can be changed to suit your needs.